# Update Character Variables based on String Pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I currently have the below vector and am trying to use `stringr` to find a pattern and update.

```
string_vector <- c("1_lasso", "_lasso", "1_lasso_olsps", "_lasso_olsps")

string_vector_new <- string_vector %>%
str_replace("^[1_]_lasso", "Lasso")

[1] "Lasso"                 "_lasso"                "Lasso_olsps"          
 [4] "_lasso_olsps"
```

I'm not sure how, but I am hoping to update my code so that I can detect a pattern like `1_lasso` and `_lasso`, and change them both to `Lasso` simultaneously. Is this possible using `stringr`? I'm not sure what regular expressions I would need to make that update and have many more variables like these ones.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `str_replace_all("1?_lasso", "Lasso")`. Do you want to replace a substring, or a whole word?

Comment: I was hoping to replace the whole word. So if it uniquely contained "_lasso" such as "1_lasso" or "_lasso", replace it with "Lasso".

Comment: Then just FYI all the answers below will replace `lasso` in `1_lassosomewordstartingwithlasso`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use the `|` character to set an "or" in the pattern.

```
str_replace_all(string_vector, "1_lasso|_lasso", "Lasso")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `sub` here with the regex pattern `[^_]*_lasso`:

```r
string_vector <- c("1_lasso", "_lasso", "1_lasso_olsps", "_lasso_olsps")
output <- sub("[^_]*_lasso", "Lasso", string_vector)
output

[1] "Lasso"       "Lasso"       "Lasso_olsps" "Lasso_olsps"
```

The pattern used here matches `_lasso` which may or may not be preceded by some number of non underscore characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```r
str_replace_all(string_vector, "\\b1?_lasso(?![^\\W_])", "Lasso")
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/CiZJP0/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1?                       '1' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _lasso                   '_lasso'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\W_]                   any character except: non-word
                             characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _),
                             '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

[**R code* snippet*](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyczqSixqFKjuKQoMy@9SJMLwogvS00uyS9SsNFVSNZQMozPSSwuzlfSUVBCsKCC8fk5xQXFCCkoH2xQfFFqQU5icmp8Yk6OBorBQOUxMUmG9hA9GvaK0XExMeHxsZogg3zAVmj@/w8A):

```r
library(stringr)
string_vector <- c("1_lasso", "_lasso", "1_lasso_olsps", "_lasso_olsps")
str_replace_all(string_vector, "\\b1?_lasso(?![^\\W_])", "Lasso")
```

**Results**: `[1] "Lasso"       "Lasso"       "Lasso_olsps" "Lasso_olsps"`

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use regular expression then this my solution.

You can directly tackle it this way.

```
    string_vector <- c("1_lasso", "_lasso", "1_lasso_olsps", "_lasso_olsps")
    gsub("1_lasso|_lasso","Lasso",string_vector)

[1] "Lasso"       "Lasso"       "Lasso_olsps" "Lasso_olsps"
```

The code searches for the two patterns and replaces it with "Lasso"

To make it more generalized we can use the below code which looks for any pattern with "something_lasso"

```
gsub("\\S*_lasso","Lasso",string_vector)
[1] "Lasso"       "Lasso"       "Lasso_olsps" "Lasso_olsps"
```

The code looks for \S*_lasso where \S* is any non space item, 0 or infinite number of times.

I hope it helps.